# pyspark phoenix NullPointerException

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-phoenix, apache-spark-sql

trying to load data to spark from hbase 1.1 using phoenix-spark 4.9.0 on spark 2.1 but failing on following error:

```
>>> df = spark.read.format('org.apache.phoenix.spark').option('table', 'namespace.table').option('zkUrl', '10.0.1.1:2181').load()

: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$13.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2432)
at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$13.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2352)
at org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixContextExecutor.call(PhoenixContextExecutor.java:76)
at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.init(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2352)
at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.getConnectionQueryServices(PhoenixDriver.java:232)
at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.createConnection(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:147)
at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.connect(PhoenixDriver.java:202)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.util.ConnectionUtil.getConnection(ConnectionUtil.java:98)
at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.util.ConnectionUtil.getInputConnection(ConnectionUtil.java:57)
at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.util.ConnectionUtil.getInputConnection(ConnectionUtil.java:45)
at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.util.PhoenixConfigurationUtil.getSelectColumnMetadataList(PhoenixConfigurationUtil.java:279)
at org.apache.phoenix.spark.PhoenixRDD.toDataFrame(PhoenixRDD.scala:114)
at org.apache.phoenix.spark.PhoenixRelation.schema(PhoenixRelation.scala:60)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.LogicalRelation.<init>(LogicalRelation.scala:40)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.baseRelationToDataFrame(SparkSession.scala:389)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:146)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:125)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

any clues anyone?